# Hashet union with preserving values from combined items

Tags: c#, linq, hash, aggregate-functions, hashset

I am looking for efficient way to combine multiple hashsets (based on object key) while preserving non key values (such as Version below).

```
class MyObject {
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public long Version {get; set;}
    override GetHashCode() { *key* }
    override Equals(...) { *key* }
}
```

in the and, i need to combine hash sets into a master list, but also all Versions.

I can make the union of 3 sets in this way:

```
for (var o in List1.Union(List2).Union(List3))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", o.Key, o.Version)
```

this only shows the versions from one of the lists (List1, or whatever list contains the item).

I need to compile these into a result with all versions..

Something i **wish** i could do like this:

```
for (var o in List1.Union(List2).Union(List3).Select((a,b,c) => new DiffObj(){Key=a.Key,VersionA=a.Version,VersionB=b.Version,VersionC=c.Version}))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1},{2},{3}", o.Key, o.VrsionA, o.VersionB, VersionC);
```

is that possible with hashsets?

**update**

it is important to keep track which list had which version (in the final result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a grouping:

```
var grouped = list1.Select(x => new { List=1, Item=x })
                   .Concat(list2.Select(x => new { List=2, Item=x }))
                   .Concat(list3.Select(x => new { List=3, Item=x }))
                   .GroupBy(pair => pair.Item);
```

Then you can just iterate over each group, which will contain equal values according to `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but which can still be distinct. The `List` value will indicate which list each item came from.

Comment: once i concatenate, i will lose the origin of which list the object came from right? I need explicit knowledge of which source (list) had which version.

Comment: @SonicSoul: That wasn't clear from the question... please be more specific in the future. Editing...

Comment: thanks Jon. yep that will do it. i wasn't even thinking of doing a group by, because i thought there is a more efficient way around hashset union..

Comment: @SonicSoul: Bear in mind that groupings will still use hashing behind the scenes - it's basically a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`